# Generic interface declaration not working as-is on typescript 0.9.5

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that defines a generic method, that returns a generic instance. For type safety I put some retractions to the type of the returned instances.

Here is some sample code:

```
class Animal {
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    name: string;
}

interface IGreeter {
    greet<T extends Animal>(): T;
}

class Greeter implements IGreeter {
    greet<T extends Animal>(): T {
        return new Dog();
    }
}

var dog = new Greeter().greet<Dog>();
dog.name = "Poochie";
```

The code above does not compile because of the error stated below. But I don't find the root cause of the error from the message, I suspect is something related to the spec, but the error message is not helpful and I can't find the response in the spec documents.

Here is the error that I get for the Greeter class:

```
Class Greeter declares interface IGreeter but does not implement it:
Types of property 'greet' of types 'Greeter' and 'IGreeter' are incompatible:
Call signatures of types '<T extends Animal>() => T' and
                         '<T extends Animal>() => T' are incompatible.
```

Finally, this code is a simplified version of a complex structure I have on a larger solution, the code worked on TypeScript 0.9.1.1 but broke after upgrading to 0.9.5.

[Here is the live version with the error on the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0A%09name%3a%20string;%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IGreeter%20%7B%0A%09greet%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E%28%29%3a%20T;%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Greeter%20implements%20IGreeter%20%7B%0A%09greet%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E%28%29%3a%20T%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20new%20Dog%28%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20dog%20=%20new%20Greeter%28%29.greet%3CDog%3E%28%29;%0Adog.name%20=%20%22Poochie%22;)

[Here is the 0.9.5 spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf)

Finally I found a way to make it somehow-work, replacing T by Animal in the interface declaration, but I can't find why this implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. Seems like a bug in TS 0.9.5. You can report it here : http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Is a bug indeed, the bug is now fixed in the development branch. https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1983