# Weird error when overloading methods with generics

Tags: typescript

I have a class which implements an interface. Both define a method which takes in a generic and outputs an Array of the same type as the generic. I'm getting a weird error about inconsistencies between the class and the interface and I'm not sure how to solve it.  Here is some sample code:

```
class Random implements IRandom {
    generateArray<T>(method: string): Array<T>;
    generateArray<T>(Constructor: new () => T): Array<T>;
    generateArray(method: any) {
        return new Array<any>();
    }
}

interface IRandom {
    generateArray<T>(method: string): Array<T>;
    generateArray<T>(Constructor: new () => T): Array<T>;
}
```

Here is an error snippet for the above code:

```
Class Random declares interface IRandom but does not implement it:
    Types of property 'generateArray' of types 'Random' and 'IRandom' are incompatible:
        Call signatures of types '{ <T>(method: string): T[]; <T>(Constructor: new() => T): T[]; }' and '{ <T>(method: string): T[]; <T>(Constructor: new() => T): T[]; }' are incompatible:
            Types of property 'concat' of types '{}[]' and 'T[]' are incompatible:
                Call signatures of types '{ <U extends T[]>(...items: U[]): {}[]; (...items: {}[]): {}[]; }' and '{ <U extends T[]>(...items: U[]): T[]; (...items: T[]): T[]; }' are incompatible:
                    Types of property 'pop' of types '{}[]' and 'T[]' are incompatible:
                        Call signatures of types '() => {}' and '() => T' are incompatible.
```

Has anyone encountered this error? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Your code compiles for me. Do you have the latest version of typescript installed?

Comment: I'm using the plugin for VS 2013, running v0.9.5.  Is there a newer version? Perhaps I should reinstall.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic interface declaration not working as-is on typescript 0.9.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437528/generic-interface-declaration-not-working-as-is-on-typescript-0-9-5)

Comment: It's a bug. It doesn't work if you use the current version available on the typescript playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stumbled across a bug - but it [has been fixed](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1983) (so will come out with the next release)...

In the meantime, there are two workarounds available...

Make The Interface And Class Generic (rather than the method).

```
interface IRandom<T> {
    generateArray(method: string): T[];
    generateArray(Constructor: new () => T): T[];
}

class Random<T> implements IRandom<T> {
    generateArray(method: string): T[];
    generateArray(Constructor: new () => T): T[];
    generateArray(method: any) {
        return new Array<any>();
    }
}
```

Or define the interface using the class (as a temporary measure). This would allow you to turn the tables when the bug is fixed by removing the `extends Random`, adding back in the interface body and putting back the `implements IRandom`.

```
interface IRandom extends Random {

}

class Random {
    generateArray<T>(method: string): Array<T>;
    generateArray<T>(Constructor: new () => T): Array<T>;
    generateArray(method: any) {
        return new Array<any>();
    }
}
```

All of the calling code would be unaware of the deception:

```
function paramIsInterface(param: IRandom) {
    // Stuff
}

var r = new Random();

paramIsInterface(r); // Accepts Random is an IRandom...
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to go with option 2 for the time being.